# converting MIAMIA305 to map in R

Tags: r

I have got a little problem. I have data which I want to map but the thing is that I dont have real location names just the short forms like: SANSAN210 OR miamia305 which I think is the the state and the county and the area code phone number. Does anyone how to convert this so I can map it on the us map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the area code (or possibly the county-areacode intersection).  There are area code maps as shapefiles.  Use `readShapePoly` or `readOGR` and merge the two.